# Vue Set Data on Mapbox Click

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-marker

I'm using Mapbox to drop a marker on a map click.  I successfully get the coordinates however I can't bind them to my data...

```
         map.on('click', function(e) {
            if (this.marker) { this.marker.remove() }
            this.marker = new mapboxgl.Marker()
            .setLngLat({ lng: e.lngLat.lng, lat: e.lngLat.lat})
            .addTo(map);
            map.flyTo({
                center: { lng: e.lngLat.lng, lat: e.lngLat.lat },
                zoom: 15
            });

            // This does not bind and update the data
            this.latitude = JSON.stringify(e.lngLat.lat)
            this.longitude = JSON.stringify(e.lngLat.lng)


        })
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's  a `contextual binding` issue. the `this` here does not refer to your `vue` instance but the `map` instead.

```
// fat arrow solves this
map.on('click', function(e) => {

})

// aliasing solves this
const self = this
map.on('click', function(e) {

})

// binding solves this
map.on('click', function(e) => {

}.bind(this))
```